# ValueError: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота для одобрения/отказа заявок, долгое время не мог понять как внедрить кнопки с причинами отказа. Сейчас добавил, при нажатии на нее получаю ошибку

```
File handle_approve_reject
    action, application_id = call.data.split("_")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Пытался исправить, никак не могу, буду благодарен любой помощи.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data.startswith(("approve_", "reject_")))
def handle_approve_reject(call):
    """Обработчик кнопок Одобрить/Отказать."""
    db_connection = sqlite3.connect('applications.db')
    db_cursor = db_connection.cursor()
    action, application_id = call.data.split("_")
    application_id = application_id.strip()

# Get application data from the database
db_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM applications WHERE id=?", (application_id,))
application_data = db_cursor.fetchone()

if application_data:
    context = {
        'user_chat_id': application_data[2],
        'nickname': application_data[3],
        'current_position': application_data[4],
        'desired_position': application_data[5],
        'status': application_data[8]
    }

    if action == "approve":
        new_status = f"Одобрено by: @{call.from_user.username}"
        # Отправляем пользователю сообщение о одобрении заявки
        user_chat_id = context['user_chat_id']
        bot.send_message(user_chat_id, f" Ваша заявка на повышение на должность '{context['desired_position']}' одобрена by: @{call.from_user.username}")

    elif action == "reject":
        new_status = f"Отказано by: @{call.from_user.username}"
        # Отправляем пользователю сообщение об отказе заявки
        user_chat_id = context['user_chat_id']
        # Create inline keyboard with rejection reasons
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
        inline_buttons = [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Неверный скриншот", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_1"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Старый скриншот", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_2"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Неустойка минимального срока для повышения", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_3"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Недостаточно баллов", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_4"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Есть активное предупреждение", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_5"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Есть активный выговор", callback_data=f"reject_reason_{application_id}_6"),
        ]
        keyboard.add(*inline_buttons)

        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=management_chat_id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text="Выберите причину отказа:", reply_markup=keyboard, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')

        return
    # Update status in the database
    db_cursor.execute("UPDATE applications SET status=? WHERE id=?", (new_status, application_id))
    db_connection.commit()
    
    # Edit the message to remove inline buttons and update the status
    new_message_text = f"От: {context['nickname']}\n" \
                       f"Текущая должность: {context['current_position']}\n" \
                       f"Желаемая должность: {context['desired_position']}\n" \
                       f"Статус: {new_status}\n"\
                       f"Причина отказа: "
    # Update the message to add the selected rejection reason
    selected_reason = get_selected_rejection_reason(call.data)  # Implement this function to retrieve the selected reason
    new_message_text += selected_reason


    bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=management_chat_id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                          text=new_message_text, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
else:
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id, "Извините, произошла ошибка при обработке заявки.")

def get_selected_rejection_reason(callback_data):
    # Split the callback data by underscores and take the last part as the reason number
    parts = callback_data.split('_')
    if len(parts) >= 4:  # Check if there are enough parts
        reason_number = parts[-1]
        reasons = {
            '1': "Неверный скриншот",
            '2': "Старый скриншот",
            '3': "Неустойка минимального срока для повышения",
            '4': "Недостаточно баллов",
            '5': "Есть активное предупреждение",
            '6': "Есть активный выговор",
        }
        return reasons.get(reason_number, "Неизвестная причина")
    else:
        return "Ошибка при получении причины отказа"
```

Comment: Видимо, в `call.data` не оказалось символа `_`.

Comment: В application id есть этот символ

Comment: Причём же здесь `application_id`? Вы его объявляете после того как делите `call.data`, вас это не смущает?

Comment: Я его объявляю в другой функции.

```insert_data = (
            application_id,
            datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),  # Current date and time
            context['user_chat_id'],
            nickname,
            context['current_position'],
            context['desired_position'],
            context['first_screenshot'].file_id,
            context['second_screenshot'].file_id,
            "На рассмотрении",  # Initial status
            "None"
        )```